# How to change the permission of a symbolic link file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, symbolic-link

When I create a symbolic link file in bash, the permission is set to [lrwxrwxrwx]. I want to change the permission of this file to [lrwxr-xr-x].
What should I do? on linux

Comment: Why? The permissions of symbolic links are never used.

Comment: [lrwxrwxrwx] is the first evidence that l is a symbolic link.

Comment: This might help: [How to change the Symlink permission?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293763/74329)

Comment: Same case with me, thank you. I'll refer to the contents of the link

Answer (score 1):

When you try to use chmod to set the link's permissions, the actually you do is to set the permissions of the link's target.The link's permissions are meaningless.
See this, for whatever permissions you want:

```
1=execute permission 
2=write permission
4=read permission 
chmod 777 file  here
```

7=rwx=1+2+4 and each 7 has permissions for o=owner,u=owner's
 read more [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Now your question bellow will work for you:

```
chmod 755 filename
```

Comment: Can't you set the link target's permission and the link's permission differently?

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand the code from the example while studying shell scripts.
If a's permissions and links are drwxr--xr-x 2
The permission of d and the number of links is lrwxr-xr-x 1, and the symbolic link is d->a.
 At this time, I'm wondering if these two privileges can be set: [drwxr--xr-x] and [lrwxr-xr-x].

Comment: Currently, I have linked, but I am not able to set the permission of d as above.

Comment: and I can set permissions using chmod but [lrwxrwxrwx] doesn't change